# HTML 5 canvas element internals not displayed when using external JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a chrome extension and I have a canvas element inside of the popup.html file and some js in an external js file as Chrome does not allow for inline scripts on chrome extension pages. The canvas element loads sucessfully as I can see the border that I put around it but the code that fills it in is executing but not doing anything. I have tested the code using inline js on a plain html file using same parameters and it works. What am I doing wrong?
HTML file:

```
  <button id="playTetrisButton" onclick="executeGame()">Play now!</button>(this button does not actually do anything as I stripped away its function for debugging and code will run without it)
  <center><canvas width="320" height="500" id="game"></canvas></center>
  <script src="tetris game code.js"></script>
```

JS FILE:

```
// This is the game code for tetris so not part of the actual website
// https://tetris.fandom.com/wiki/Tetris_Guideline

// get a random integer between the range of [min,max]
document.addEventListener('DOMCONTENTLOADED',domloaded,false);
function domloaded(){


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// generate a new tetromino sequence
// @see https://tetris.fandom.com/wiki/Random_Generator
function generateSequence() {
  const sequence = ['I', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'T', 'Z'];

  while (sequence.length) {
    const rand = getRandomInt(0, sequence.length - 1);
    const name = sequence.splice(rand, 1)[0];
    tetrominoSequence.push(name);
  }
}

// get the next tetromino in the sequence
function getNextTetromino() {
  if (tetrominoSequence.length === 0) {
    generateSequence();
  }

  const name = tetrominoSequence.pop();
  const matrix = tetrominos[name];

  // I and O start centered, all others start in left-middle
  const col = playfield[0].length / 2 - Math.ceil(matrix[0].length / 2);

  // I starts on row 21 (-1), all others start on row 22 (-2)
  const row = name === 'I' ? -1 : -2;

  return {
    name: name,      // name of the piece (L, O, etc.)
    matrix: matrix,  // the current rotation matrix
    row: row,        // current row (starts offscreen)
    col: col         // current col
  };
}

// rotate an NxN matrix 90deg
// @see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/186834
function rotate(matrix) {
  const N = matrix.length - 1;
  const result = matrix.map((row, i) =>
    row.map((val, j) => matrix[N - j][i])
  );

  return result;
}

// check to see if the new matrix/row/col is valid
function isValidMove(matrix, cellRow, cellCol) {
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] && (
          // outside the game bounds
          cellCol + col < 0 ||
          cellCol + col >= playfield[0].length ||
          cellRow + row >= playfield.length ||
          // collides with another piece
          playfield[cellRow + row][cellCol + col])
        ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}

// place the tetromino on the playfield
function placeTetromino() {
  for (let row = 0; row < tetromino.matrix.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < tetromino.matrix[row].length; col++) {
      if (tetromino.matrix[row][col]) {

        // game over if piece has any part offscreen
        if (tetromino.row + row < 0) {
          return showGameOver();
        }

        playfield[tetromino.row + row][tetromino.col + col] = tetromino.name;
      }
    }
  }

  // check for line clears starting from the bottom and working our way up
  for (let row = playfield.length - 1; row >= 0; ) {
    if (playfield[row].every(cell => !!cell)) {

      // drop every row above this one
      for (let r = row; r >= 0; r--) {
        for (let c = 0; c < playfield[r].length; c++) {
          playfield[r][c] = playfield[r-1][c];
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      row--;
    }
  }

  tetromino = getNextTetromino();
}

// show the game over screen
function showGameOver() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
  gameOver = true;

  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.globalAlpha = 0.75;
  context.fillRect(0, canvas.height / 2 - 30, canvas.width, 60);

  context.globalAlpha = 1;
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.font = '36px monospace';
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.textBaseline = 'middle';
  context.fillText('GAME OVER!', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const grid = 32;
const tetrominoSequence = [];

// keep track of what is in every cell of the game using a 2d array
// tetris playfield is 10x20, with a few rows offscreen
const playfield = [];

// populate the empty state
for (let row = -2; row < 20; row++) {
  playfield[row] = [];

  for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
    playfield[row][col] = 0;
  }
}

// how to draw each tetromino
// @see https://tetris.fandom.com/wiki/SRS
const tetrominos = {
  'I': [
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
  ],
  'J': [
    [1,0,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'L': [
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'O': [
    [1,1],
    [1,1],
  ],
  'S': [
    [0,1,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'Z': [
    [1,1,0],
    [0,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'T': [
    [0,1,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ]
};

// color of each tetromino
const colors = {
  'I': 'cyan',
  'O': 'yellow',
  'T': 'purple',
  'S': 'green',
  'Z': 'red',
  'J': 'blue',
  'L': 'orange'
};

let count = 0;
let tetromino = getNextTetromino();
let rAF = null;  // keep track of the animation frame so we can cancel it
let gameOver = false;

// game loop
function loop() {
  rAF = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  // draw the playfield
  for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
      if (playfield[row][col]) {
        const name = playfield[row][col];
        context.fillStyle = colors[name];

        // drawing 1 px smaller than the grid creates a grid effect
        context.fillRect(col * grid, row * grid, grid-1, grid-1);
      }
    }
  }

  // draw the active tetromino
  if (tetromino) {

    // tetromino falls every 35 frames
    if (++count > 35) {
      tetromino.row++;
      count = 0;

      // place piece if it runs into anything
      if (!isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, tetromino.row, tetromino.col)) {
        tetromino.row--;
        placeTetromino();
      }
    }

    context.fillStyle = colors[tetromino.name];

    for (let row = 0; row < tetromino.matrix.length; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < tetromino.matrix[row].length; col++) {
        if (tetromino.matrix[row][col]) {

          // drawing 1 px smaller than the grid creates a grid effect
          context.fillRect((tetromino.col + col) * grid, (tetromino.row + row) * grid, grid-1, grid-1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// listen to keyboard events to move the active tetromino
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (gameOver) return;

  // left and right arrow keys (move)
  if (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39) {
    const col = e.which === 37
      ? tetromino.col - 1
      : tetromino.col + 1;

    if (isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, tetromino.row, col)) {
      tetromino.col = col;
    }
  }

  // up arrow key (rotate)
  if (e.which === 38) {
    const matrix = rotate(tetromino.matrix);
    if (isValidMove(matrix, tetromino.row, tetromino.col)) {
      tetromino.matrix = matrix;
    }
  }

  // down arrow key (drop)
  if(e.which === 40) {
    const row = tetromino.row + 1;

    if (!isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, row, tetromino.col)) {
      tetromino.row = row - 1;

      placeTetromino();
      return;
    }

    tetromino.row = row;
  }
});
}
```

Comment: When _popup.html_ is displayed, are there any errors in the console? Specifically, right click the pop page and select `Inspect`

Comment: No I solved my issue by using a different open-source version of the code but I think the problem was something with script execution timing and the script would be executed after it was loaded but before it was rendered